# What fantasy work has a quote about “pawns on a chessboard too large to see the edges”?

Tags: story-identification, quotes

> “*We are but pawns on a chessboard too large to see the edges* ”

I remember hearing this in a TV show a few years back. I'm fairly certain it had a fantasy/medieval setting; my first guess was Tywin Lannister from Game of Thrones. But all my Google search results, even with lots of variations (*e.g.* pieces instead of pawns, end instead of edge) have turned up nothing.

I often remember hearing things that I actually read, so it's possible it's from a book.

Comment: Sounds like something that Kapela would say in Alan Moore's Top Ten comic (issue 8, I believe). He's a player in the "great game", the chessboard in the sky, and he's dying. I'd re-read it to check, but my copy is packed away at the moment.

Comment: @MarkThompson: I don't think I've ever read that comic series, but it's possible I read something from it online. Thanks anyways, I'll try to look into it.

Comment: Kinda sounds like something from Blade Runner. It's not, but it kinda sounds like it.

Comment: "We're pawns on the chess table. Pawns hop around the board in complete ignorance of what's going on.... The game is too big and complicated for pawns." [Don's Nam by Franklin Rast, p. 145](http://books.google.com/books?id=P3mFq1aei44C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q&f=false) I really doubt this is it, but thought I'd suggest it just in case.

Comment: @JustinGreer: I don't think that's it either, but thanks anyways. Even if nothing comes of this question, at least there will be some good chess quotes.

Comment: Made me think of the 80s Clash of the Titans or Diskworld, but not it.

Comment: This is similar to a quotation from *Alice Through The Looking Glass* but not an exact match.

Comment: Interestingly, this is also reminiscent of a [quote by physicist Richard Feynman](https://en.chessbase.com/post/feynman-using-chess-to-explain-science).

Comment: It WAS a game of thrones quote. I'm trying to source it right now, but I can't remember who said it. Pretty sure it was Tyrion, but it may have only been on the show and not in the books...

Comment: 99.9% sure it wasn't Game of Thrones. a) Chess doesn't exist in Game of Thrones world, there's a chess-like game in the books with different pieces, but not chess, b) [a search on a transcript site](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:transcripts.foreverdreaming.org+%22game+of+thrones%22+pawns) suggests "pawn" (and also "chess") never appeared in any GoT script, only gives other shows, c) pretty sure I'd have remembered it

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if it is from Sheri Tepper's 'The True Game', where the people are the pieces, each with powers/rules, and game against each other.
I don't have a copy with me to check for you, but if not, I still recommend it as a good read.

Comment: This is really low quality unless you back it up with references, establishing that this is in fact the correct answer

Comment: @Aegon: I wouldn’t say it’s particularly low quality. There’s enough detail to justify it as a possibility, and allow others to check.

Answer (score 2):

Found a couple of contenders. But don't seem to be the right subject matter.

[Darwin's Bass: The Evolutionary Psychology of Fishing Man](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JUiN1HN6OZEC&pg=PT249&lpg=PT249&dq=%22we%20are%20but%20pawns%22&source=bl&ots=wcY4yUO_io&sig=1xANiliW1QPsN-AdQ7zZVCGM7ps&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjur9KblaDOAhWHIsAKHdwlD0cQ6AEIPjAI#v=onepage&q=%22we%20are%20but%20pawns%22&f=false)

> We are but pawns in some great unknowable game.

[Birch Shadow of The Cat: When Dark Forces Awaken, a Magician and his Pupil](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LaaaAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA176&dq=%22we+are+but+pawns%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0l-rqlaDOAhUEIsAKHV9XDoU4ChDoAQglMAI#v=onepage&q=%22we%20are%20but%20pawns%22&f=false)

> We are but pawns in a universal game of chess

Comment: ['Tis all a Chequer-board of Nights and Days
 Where Destiny with Men for Pieces plays:
   Hither and thither moves, and mates, and slays,
 And one by one back in the Closet lays.](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/246)

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly from David Edding's "Belgariad". The protagonist is often reminded of the fact they they are just pieces of a much larger game and the books are even named after chess moves.

Comment: The series name is "Belgariad" (the main character is initially called "Garion" and later "Belgarion", which may be the source of your confusion).  It's been a long while since I read these books, so I can't rule it out, but I don't *remember* anything like the quote in the question being in them.  You're right that it would fit thematically, though.

Comment: @Jules The thought first occurs to Garion in Vo Mimbre in the throneroom the first time he's there.  Don't think it ever says chess or pawn, but he does picture the two prophecies playing a great game.  [page 123](https://books.google.com/books?id=kJQLCwe3Ya8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:0345335651&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii0_uM2JnXAhWBzIMKHQxxAgcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)